# Limit WooCommerce product title to a specific length (and add '...')

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, string-length

I'm trying to limit the number of characters our WooCommerce product titles have, I found this PHP code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ! is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, 30); // change last number to the number of characters you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

It works but I would like it to show the "..." at the end of each product title.

Comment: Replace `return substr( $title, 0, 30);`with `return substr( $title, 0, 30) . '…';`

Comment: One more question: How do I remove the '...' from product titles that are shorter than the maximum lenght allowed mentioned in this code (30 in this situation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `strlen()` php function to target specific product title length to append `…` to shortened title when product title is over a specific length:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ! is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' && strlen( $title ) > 30 ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, 30) . '…'; // change last number to the number of characters you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and change the character numbers to 40 but then it goes to 2nd line and then the alignment of add to cart button disturb, it get changed from other products alignmen .

add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 ); function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) { if ( ! is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' && strlen( $title ) > 30 ) { return substr( $title, 0, 30) . '…'; // change last number to the number of characters you want } else { return $title; } }

Comment: If you have a question, it'm more appropriate to created your own topic or comment on the answer related to your issue. In your case, you are asking for help with a CSS issue related of the "accepted" answer but not about the initial question (talking about PHP). In your case, the author of the accepted answer never see your question. You will have more chance if you use the appropriate feature of stackoverflow for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with CSS by adding the following style attributes to the element containing the content you want to ellipsize. This would ensure that the content always displays to the edge of the element, without over-flowing.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This method should be more performant than the JS solution and when implementing functionality like this, I'd always choose a pure-CSS solution if possible, before reverting to Javascript or trimming the string on the backend.

Answer (score -1):

```
white-space: nowrap;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.